# refresh_token grant_type error: UserDetailsService is required. But I dont want to specify one

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, refresh-token

I'm trying to create an Oauth authentication/authorization server using spring boot and dependencies
 * spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure
 * nimbus-jose-jwt

and I'm following [docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-authorization-server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security-oauth2-authorization-server)

The issue is that I don't want to specify a UserDetailsService since the information about the user account is in another service that doesn't expose passwords. That service just has an API in which input is user/pass and output is user info (if the user exists/credentials are correct).

So my code/configuration is a little deviated from the documentation.

```
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

     //injections

   @Override
   public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
       endpoints
               .tokenStore(jwtTokenStore)
               .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter)
               .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
   }
}
```

and

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   //injections

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(travelerAuthenticationProvider); //my custom // authentication provider that calls the other service for checking credentials
    }
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class TravelerAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TravelerAuthenticationProvider.class);

    private OrderTravelerProfileClient travelerProfileClient;

    public TravelerAuthenticationProvider(OrderTravelerProfileClient travelerProfileClient) {
        this.travelerProfileClient = travelerProfileClient;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (authentication.getName() == null || (authentication.getCredentials().toString().isEmpty())) {
            return null;
        }
        var username = authentication.getName();
        var password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        try {
            travelerProfileClient.authenticate(username, password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("checking traveler {} credentials failed", username, e);
            throw new BadCredentialsException("wrong traveler credentials");
        }
        var authorities = Set.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("traveler"));
        var updatedAuthentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, authorities);
        return updatedAuthentication;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Everything related to client_credentials and password flow works but when I try to use refresh_token flow, it complains that `UserDetailsService is required`. How should I solve the issue without defining a UserDetailsService and just relaying on my custom authentication provider?

**UPDATE**:
apparently refresh_token flow has a recheck for authentication (credentials) which needs another authentication provider for type PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken.class.

So I created a new auth provider like this:

```
@Component
public class TravelerRefreshTokenBasedAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TravelerRefreshTokenBasedAuthenticationProvider.class);


    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        var currentAuthentication = (PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken) authentication;
            //.....
        return updatedAuthentication;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

and update my security configs to:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

//injections

    //this bean will be more configured by the method below and it will be used by spring boot
    //for authenticating requests. Its kind of an equivalent to userDetailsService
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(travelerUserPassBasedAuthenticationProvider);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(travelerRefreshTokenBasedAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

the issue is spring doesn't recognize my auth providers in refresh_token flow and tries to use a default one. And the default one is trying to use a UserDetailsService that doesn't exist.

I also feel that I don't need to create another provider and I can reuse the previous one. Because the check for which spring is failing to use my custom provider is a check against user/pass; which I was doing in my previous auth provider.

so all in all, until now, I feel I have to introduce my custom provider to spring differently for refresh_token flow comparing to password flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AuthenticationProvider` implementation only supports `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, which is used for username/password authentication, while the `refresh_token` flow tries to renew authentication using `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken` (see [DefaultTokenServices.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/token/DefaultTokenServices.java#L150)).

So you need to create another `AuthenticationProvider` for `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken` and add it to `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`.

**Update:**

I've found that `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer` creates a new instance of `DefaultTokenServices`, if none is assigned, which in turn creates a new instance of `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` and does not use the provided `AuthenticationManager`. To avoid this, you can create your own instance of `DefaultTokenServices` and pass it to `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer`:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
    endpoints
            .tokenStore(jwtTokenStore)
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter)
            .tokenEnhancer(accessTokenConverter)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .tokenServices(createTokenServices(endpoints, authenticationManager));
}

private DefaultTokenServices createTokenServices(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
    tokenServices.setTokenStore(endpoints.getTokenStore());
    tokenServices.setClientDetailsService(endpoints.getClientDetailsService());
    tokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(endpoints.getTokenEnhancer());
    tokenServices.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    return tokenServices;
}
```

Comment: I tried it. no difference, unfortunately. My new AuthPrivoder is not called.                  @anar-sultanov

Comment: ```@Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(travelerUserPassBasedAuthenticationProvider);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(travelerRefreshTokenBasedAuthenticationProvider);
    }```

Comment: I debugged the library side code (starting from the code that you linked in your example). none of my auth providers are being recognized in refresh_token flow although I introduced it to AuthenticationManagerBuilder

Comment: ```

@Component
public class TravelerRefreshTokenBasedAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
     //....authentication method
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}

```

Comment: @NeoSmith It would be more convenient if you update your answer or, even better, create a minimal reproducible example and upload it to GitHub. A little later I will try to reproduce the problem and update my answer.

Comment: I will update my question here. There is nothing special in the service other than configurations and auth providers. thanks very much

Comment: thank you man. It looks like the answer to my issue. But as I'm using JWT, I guess I need to somehow write my own token enhancer. Because with default one I get ``` "Cannot convert access token to JSON"```

Comment: I used my JWTTokenStore instead of endpoints.getTokenStore(). Because using endpoints.getTokenStore() doesn't put JWT configurations into action

Comment: Yes I used  JWTTokenConvertor.enhance() and craeted my own token enhancer and then it worked

Comment: @NeoSmith I guess your `accessTokenConverter` is instance of `JwtAccessTokenConverter` which implements `TokenEnhancer`. So you can pass it to endpoints and it will be picked up. Corrected the answer, could you please accept it if it works for you?

Comment: @NeoSmith can you please upload your solution to GitHub? I am facing similar problem and there is related Open Issue here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1800

Comment: @kmandalas man dont waste your time with spring-auth-server as it is deprecated. And it won't be continued by spring team any more in any form. I got rid of that code for this reason

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/14/spring-security-oauth-2-0-roadmap-update

Comment: @NeoSmith so which approach did you follow? Did you use a 3rd party auth-server?

Comment: I developed very minimalistic jwt issuer/verifier using one of the libraries suggested in jwt.io. it was enough for me then.